# Kentico Master Page Template Title

Tags: kentico

I am very new in Kentico and this is my first project after Kentico training.

I have read a few blogs and the Kentico documentation and as per knowledge base I think I must use Kentico Portal approach. So I have created Kentico Site using blank template, but I am not finding solution to change  prefix. I can see in my master template following HTML

```
&lt;title&gt;My Site - /&lt;/title&gt;
```

So is there any way I can remove "`My Site -`" and/or replace with something else?

Again I am quite new in Kentico so any help or comments will be very valuable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the portal approach is a really good choice. Then you can do almost everything inside the Kentico environment without using external tools like Visual Studio and using the strength that the Kentico engine has to offer.

But to answer your real question about the page title you need to go to :
**Settings -> Select your site on the left top of your screen -> Content -> Below you have an section “Metadata” and the option to change the “Page title prefix”** (in Kentico v7 and higher)

Good luck with your very first steps on Kentico and if you have questions you can always ask them here on StackOverflow or on http://devnet.kentico.com/questions-answers.

Comment: At least in version 7 and below, these settings are found in Site Manager.